# Optimizing Code - getValue() and looping

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a bit of newbie at coding, especially Javascript/Google-script language. I've created the code below, and it works, but now that I've got a working code I'd like to see how I can optimize it. It seems to me that all of the getValue() calls are a major performance hit, and I've never really been good at optimizing loops. Anyone know a better way to accomplish the same as this code?

What it does: Checks each spreadsheet in one of my folders to see if it needs to have the rest of the script run. If true, it opens that sheet and counts the number of rows that have data, using that to limit the amount of rows it checks in the loop. It then looks for any row marked for push and copies that range to another spreadsheet in my drive. It then continues to the next file in the folder and does the same.

Here's my code:

```
function myVupdate() {  
  try {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("123abc"),
        files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next(),
        sss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sss);

    //Work orders update
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"),
        refresh = ss.getRange("W3").getValue();
    if (refresh == 0) {continue};
    var avals = ss.getRange("D5:D").getValues(),
        count = avals.filter(String).length,
        rows = count + 5
    var val = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  
  for (var row=5; row < rows; row++) {
    var cell = ss.getDataRange().getCell(row, 23).getValue();
    if (cell == 0) {        
      var cells = [["v" + "WO-" + val[row-1][3] + "_" + val[row-1][2],val[row-1][13],val[row-1][14],val[row-1][15],new Date()]];
      var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("target_spreadsheet"),
          ts = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
      ts.insertRowBefore(2);
      var last_hmy = ts.getRange(3,1).getValue();
      ts.getRange(2,1).setValue(last_hmy+1);
      ts.getRange(2,2,cells.length,cells[0].length).setValues(cells);
      ts.getRange(2,7).setValue(sss.getName());
      ss.getRange(row,17).setValue(last_hmy+1);
      ss.getRange(row,18,cells.length,cells[0].length).setValues(cells);

      //Turnover update
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
        avals = ss.getRange("D5:D").getValues(),
        count = avals.filter(String).length,
        rows = count + 5
    var val = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    }
  }  
  for (var row=5; row < rows; row++) {
    var cell = ss.getDataRange().getCell(row, 24).getValue();
    if (cell == 0) {

      var cells = [["v" + val[row-1][3] + "_" + val[row-1][2],val[row-1][12],val[row-1][15],val[row-1][16],new Date()]];
      var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("target_spreadsheet"),
          ts = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
      ts.insertRowBefore(2);
      var last_hmy = ts.getRange(3,1).getValue();
      ts.getRange(2,1).setValue(last_hmy+1);
      ts.getRange(2,2,cells.length,cells[0].length).setValues(cells);
      ts.getRange(2,7).setValue(sss.getName());
      ss.getRange(row,18).setValue(last_hmy+1);
      ss.getRange(row,19,cells.length,cells[0].length).setValues(cells);
    }
  }
  }
 }
  catch(e) {
   // Browser.msgBox("An error occured. A log has been sent for review.");
    var errorSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById ("target_sheet").getSheetByName("Error Log"),
    source = sss.getName();
    lastRow = errorSheet.getLastRow();
    var cell = errorSheet.getRange('A1');
    cell.offset(lastRow, 0).setValue(e.message);
    cell.offset(lastRow, 1).setValue(e.fileName);
    cell.offset(lastRow, 2).setValue(e.lineNumber);
    cell.offset(lastRow, 3).setValue(source);
    cell.offset(lastRow, 4).setValue(new Date());
    MailApp.sendEmail("my@email.com", "Error report - " + new Date(),
      "\r\nSource: " + source + "\r\n"
      + "\r\nMessage: " + e.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + e.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + e.lineNumber
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow,

first of all, you are correct. The more `getValue()`, or `setValue()` calls you do the worse the performance, read more on best practices [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices). Google recommends you batch these as much as possible. One thing that immediately springs to attention is the following:

```
var val = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
```

so now you have all the values on the sheet in a 2D array. That means that in the following bit

```
var ss = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"),
        refresh = ss.getRange("W3").getValue();
    if (refresh == 0) {continue};
    var avals = ss.getRange("D5:D").getValues(),
        count = avals.filter(String).length,
        rows = count + 5
    var val = ss.getDataRange().getValues();  
  for (var row=5; row < rows; row++) {
    var cell = ss.getDataRange().getCell(row, 23).getValue();
```

every single `getValue()` or `getValues()` is no longer necessary. Instead, you know that `refresh = val[2][22]` because you need the 3rd row and 23rd column, as you already have the entire range that has data from that sheet.

Same with `avals` as all values in range `D5:D` are in `vals[n][3]`, where `n` starts from `4`. **Remember, the array index starts from 0** (so first row and first column is `vals[0][0]`.

So anywhere you are trying to use `getValues()` from the `ss` spreadsheet, you already have that data. What you can also do, is manipulate the array you have, so you always change the values only in that array. Once you are done with it, you use `ss.getDataRange().setValues(vals)` to push the entire array back to the same range (you can just store the range in a variable like `datRange = ss.getDataRange()` and then do `datRange.setValues(vals)`.

You will just need to work with a separate data array for any other sheet. I did not go into detail for the rest of the code as the same ideas go throughout. Since you already grab everything with `getValues()` there is no longer any reason to use `getValue()` for any cell within that range.